ssl verification throws error with python 3.12 whereas in python 3.9 it succeeded
With python 3.12 I got the error:

SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000)')

But with python 3.9 its working fine (it's got successful)
libraries version i have for python 3.9:
pyasn1 - 0.4.8
pyOpenSSL - 20.0.1
requests - 2.23.0

libraries version I used for python 3.12:
pyasn1 - 0.6.0
pyOpenssl - 24.1
requests - 2.31.0

Is there anything has changed between these versions with SSL verification?
